# Viewing or Editing their own Profile who is currently login

Tags: python, django

I am editing profile using Django framework. The problem lies where the user login can see the profile of other user when they change the **id** in the web address. Could someone help me so that I can only view the user's profile who is login and if they change the **id** they will receive an error. Thanks

**Edit User Profile**

```
@login_required(login_url = 'signin')
@user_passes_test(check_role_super)
def sa_profile_edit(request, user_id=None):

    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(userMember, pk=user_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserFormAdmin(request.POST or None, instance=user)
        form_profile = MemberForm(request.POST or None, instance=user_profile)
    else:
        form = UserFormAdmin(instance=user)
        form_profile = MemberForm(instance=user_profile)       
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'user': user,
        'form_profile': form_profile,
        'user_profile': user_profile
     }
    return render(request, 'pages/sa_editProfile.html', context)
```

**If role is super**

```
def check_role_super(user):
    if user.role == 3:
        return True
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied
```

**Model**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    MEMBER = 1
    ADMIN = 2
    SUPERADMIN = 3
    ROLE_CHOICE = (
        (MEMBER, 'Member'),
        (ADMIN, 'Admin'),
        (SUPERADMIN, 'Super Admin')
    )

    ACTIVE = 1
    DELETED = 2
    DEACTIVATED = 3

    STATUS = (
        (ACTIVE, 'Active'),
        (DELETED, 'Deleted'),
        (DEACTIVATED, 'Deactivated')
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Some String")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length = 100, db_index=True, null = True, 
validators=[
    
            RegexValidator(
                regex='^(\+\d{1,3})?,?\s?\d{8,13}',
                message='Phone number must not consist of space and requires country 
code. eg : +639171234567',
            ),
        ])
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 100,validators=[MinLengthValidator(8),
        
        ])
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS, blank=True, null=True)

# required fields
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superadmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'mobile_number']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    def get_role(self):
        if self.role == 1:
            user_role = 'Member'
        elif self.role == 2:
            user_role = 'Admin'
        elif self.role == 3:
            user_role = 'Super Admin'
        return user_role

    def get_status(self):
        if self.status == 1:
            user_status = 'Active'
        elif self.status == 2:
            user_status = 'Deleted'
        elif self.status == 3:
            user_status = 'Deactivated'
        return user_status

class userMember(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/profile_pictures', blank=True, null=True)
    cover_color = ColorField(format='hexa', blank=True, null=True)
    upload_id = models.ImageField(upload_to='member/id', blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: what does `@user_passes_test(check_role_super)` tag do?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current user from the request instead, replace `user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)` with:

```
user = request.user
if not user.is_authenticated:
    raise Http404()
```

Answer (score 0):

========= view.py ===========

```
# User Profile Update
def ProfileView(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        form =UserProfileChangeForm(instance=request.user)
        context = {'form':form}
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form =UserProfileChangeForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                messages.info(request,'Profile Successfully Updated')
                return redirect('/profile/')
            else:
                form =UserProfileChangeForm(instance=request.user)
                user_data = request.user
                context = {'form':form,'user_data':user_data}
                return rend
```

er(request,'profile.html',context)

======= form.py ========

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm
    
    # User Profile
    class UserProfileChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
        password =None
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ['username','first_name','last_name','email']
            widgets = {
    
            'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter Username'}),
    
            'first_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter First Name'}),
    
            'last_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter Last Name'}),
    
            'email':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter E-Mail'}),
    
        }
```

Comment: Thank you.. why was the form not saving the update. I print the error: <ul class="errorlist"><li>username<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>email<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>password<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>confirm_password<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>password_readonly<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>

Answer (score 0):

you should implement class with `UUID` concept. UUID meant to protect url address.
but as short and not ideal solution
you can overwrite id in your code by `request.user.id`
lets say logged in user has `id=3` and he tries to change it to `id=4` and then view function will get called. but you can overwrite that id by as i said above and he ll end up seeing his profile anyways. but URL WILL display wrong `id` so this is not a good option.